# Implementing email or username login using swift and Parse as a backend?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, authentication, parse-platform

I am adding the feature of using both email and username to log in to an account. The problem is the the document on Parse.com uses a username to log in, but I want the option to also log in with an email address.

This is what I found on Parse.com as a starting point:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("myname", password:"mypass") {
  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   if user != nil {
     // Do stuff after successful login.
   } else {
     // The login failed. Check error to see why.
   }
}
```

I know this is where I should start, but I do not know where to go after this. I am still new to Swift and I have been trying to find ways to implement this feature, but to no success. How can this be achieved? The help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I would like to use email and username separately. I do not want to make username and email the same.

Answer (score 0):

I just used textFields to enter in an email and password, then set the emailTextField.text as both the username and email when creating an account.  Now your email is your username! Bam.

I also kept the case for the email field, since aliases require case sensitivity, but made all the usernames lowercase, so people wouldn't have trouble logging in.